# Reading and overriding an Android source define

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I am working on an Android bluetooth LE app.
I have read in several places about a hard coded limit for the number of connected devices - [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/8dc42c603f5571047878640705eee18fa5396f11%5E%21/)

It is defined to `BTA_GATTC_NOTIF_REG_MAX` in the file `/bta/gatt/bta_gattc_int.h`

I'm just wondering if it's possible for me to read and `Log` what this value is set to on my device?

And also if it's possible to change this value in my code?

Thanks